# Apply href to div based on another element

Tags: jquery, href

EDIT - I neglected to originally state that I don't have access to change the markup.

I'm not very good with jQuery, so I've been unsuccessful in getting this to work. I need to take the href from the entry-title heading and apply it to the entry-content div.

```
<h3 class='slide-entry-title entry-title'><a href='/test-page' title='Slide 1'>Slide 1</a></h3>
<div class='slide-entry-excerpt entry-content'>
    <p><img src="/img/test-image.jpg" /></p>
</div>
```

This needs to be done for as many slides as are on the page, each having their own unique href.  The class names do not change for the other slides.

I found this code for clicking on an item, but I'm not waiting on a click... I need to apply it automatically.

```
$(".entry-content").click(function() {
  window.location = "http://yahoo.com";
});
```

Comment: add your href as a `data` attribute and access it with `$().data('my-link')` function

Comment: See clarification above... I cannot modify the markup.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to find the url of the previous `.entry-title` and use it instead of `"http://yahoo.com"`
Try this :

```
$(".entry-content").click(function () {
        let url = $(this).prev(".entry-title").children('a').attr('href');
        window.location = url;
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.  I believe I would need to use something other than .click() correct?  I want it to happen on load, so maybe .ready()?

Comment: @pburgh `.ready()` is fired when the DOM is ready, `.click()` is generally what is used for this kind of thing, you can also use `.on()` method or the `.bind()` method, exemple : `$('.entry-content').on('click', function() { /* Do Something */ });`